# ngAnimate not adding ng-enter classes

Tags: angularjs, jquery-animate

I'm diving into ngAnimate but it doesn't work how I expected. In this [Plnkr](http://embed.plnkr.co/MMEPpBIIkGpsTpwrdoyE/) I have created my project. The problem is that ngAnimate does not add the ng-enter and ng-enter-active classes to the ui-view. A weird thing: the ng-leave classes are being added.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I found out the ng-class attribute added to the ui-view is not added at the time the animation executes. When I use JQuery's addClass inside it works, is this bad practice? The class/ng-class way I got from [this article](https://scotch.io/tutorials/animating-angularjs-apps-ngview). Why is it not working for me?